# Bidirectional (BiDi) text inside HTML textarea not respecting LRM control character

Tags: html, unicode, utf, bidirectional, bidi

I'm having a hard time with making BiDi strings work inside an HTML textarea as I'd expect.

This test string contains both Arabic and English, plus sequences of pseudo-tags (<1/>, <2/>), which are composed of neutral-direction characters (<, >, /, numbers) and should inherit their direction by the strong-direction character before them.

Given that these pseudo-tags are positioned after both RTL and LTR text, I need to force the direction of the text putting one `LRM (U+200E, &lrm;)` char **before** each pseudo-tags.

The result it's not what I expected:
[image: Textarea screenshot test]

Note that the textarea has the direction property set as follow: `dir='rtl'`

Tested with both Chrome and FF, none of them seems to work as expected. Am I missing something?

Results on Jsfiddle are even different: https://jsfiddle.net/o7d2ymdc/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, displaying these inside a textarea is going to be extremely difficult, if at all possible.

There are several issues that are at play here, among them is the fact that brackets and parentheses are mirrored in the Unicode Bidirectional algorithm: This `<span dir="ltr"><</span>` is rendered as '<', while this `<span dir="rtl"><</span>` is rendered as '>'. And all of this is added on top of the fact that we have different definitions of "end of string" in either of the RTL and LTR strings.

Your best bet could be using **ContentEditable**. You can display editable rich text - that is actually html nodes - and essentially isolate your RTL pieces from the HTML markup properly with spans, as if you would have statically displayed it. However, if this textbox allows for custom user-generated text, you may need to come up with a good algorithm that wraps the bidirectional text automatically as the user types, which can be a pretty big challenge.

If this helps, you're not the only one to deal with this. If you edit HTML blocks in *Arabic Wikipedia*, for example, you will see the exact same problem (which makes editing HTML and wikitext a fairly big challenge)

This problem is also one of the reasons why people prefer a WYSIWYG editor - that has proper contextual and conceptual separation between the markup/style and the text itself.

Comment: That's they way i did it in the end. I use contenteditable elements and I intercept the keypress event so I can wrap the characters in different span elements with either dir="rtl" or dir="ltr" property